# Empty state in React, call of async function

Tags: javascript, reactjs, asynchronous

why my state is emptY?

[I just do simple thing for react, what did i miss here?](https://i.stack.imgur.com/qh7dG.png)

[image]

```
class HeroOlive extends Component {
  state = {
    phoneImg: "",
  };
  componentDidMount() {
    const { options, wpApi } = this.props;

    wpApi.getImageUrl(options.main_img).then((res) => {
      this.setState({ phoneImg: res });
    });
    console.log("OPTIONS ---- ", options);
  }
  render() {
    const { options, wpApi } = this.props;
    const { phoneImg } = this.state;
    console.log(phoneImg);
return <h1>some</h1>
}
}
```

Comment: `componentDidMount` is executed _after_ the initial render. Since initial value of `this.state.phoneImg` is an empty string, during the initial render, empty string will be logged. One the `componentDidMount` executes and updates the state, component will re-render. As a result, updated value of `phoneImg` will be logged.

Comment: Please may you edit the question and put the code into it using text? Using an image is unhelpful.

Comment: [Please do not upload images of code/errors when asking a question.](//meta.stackoverflow.com/q/285551)

Comment: When you say it is empty, do you mean an empty string, or undefined?

Comment: ok, what i have to use here? if it is to call componentDidUpdate() here? where it`s better to call    wpApi.getImageUrl(options.main_img).then((res) => {
      this.setState({ phoneImg: res });
});

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to know about `life cycle`

`componentDidMount` will run after `render` method.
[image]

Based on the diagram, (1) will be run before (2).

Useful link about [React lifecycle methods diagram](https://projects.wojtekmaj.pl/react-lifecycle-methods-diagram/)

**Note: Don't worry about the first `render`, it'll be fine when API has been done -> state changed -> render() will be run again. The purpose of `componentDidMount`  is that.**

[Demo here:](https://codesandbox.io/s/fervent-golick-iypy1?file=/src/App.js:0-642)

```
import React, { Component } from "react";

export default class App extends Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {
      phoneImg: ""
    };
  }

  componentDidMount() {
    const { options, wpApi } = this.props;
    this._getData().then((res) => {
      console.log("Waiting after 2ms ");
      this.setState({ phoneImg: res });
    });
  }

  _getData() {
    return new Promise((resolve) =>
      setTimeout(() => resolve("Your data"), 2000)
    );
  }

  render() {
    const { options, wpApi } = this.props;
    const { phoneImg } = this.state;
    console.log(phoneImg);
    return <h1>some</h1>;
  }
}
```

**Output**
[image]

Comment: It *shouldn't* be `this.state`, that's a *class field*.

Comment: Thanks. I've updated the answer, pls take a look at it. @jonrsharpe

Comment: so, do i have to do that in constructor?

Comment: Yes, you can do it to load data. However, when `componentDidMount` is run, the state has been changed then the `render` function will run again.

Comment: @plaglamist moving it to the constructor won't help (and may cause other problems) because *it's still asynchronous* - your code needs to tolerate the fact that `phoneImg` will be an empty string until the real data loads.

Comment: but anyway my state is emty in render, do i have to put componentDidUpdate? or have i should get my url string from the state?

Comment: hmmm, ok i will take a look now.

Comment: I've just updated my answer with a demo. As @jonrsharpe 's comment, You should put the call api into `componentDidMount`, dont worry about the first `render`, it'll be fine when api has been done -> state changed -> render() will be run again.

Comment: thanks a lot, i`m gonna try it in my app c: